# Question regarding the area of a region

Tags: calculus, area

I was faced with the following problem, taken from my math textbook :
Given the function $f(x)=x^2+6x+1$, find an approximation for the area encapsulated by the region $R(x,y)$ where $f(x)+f(y) \leq 0$ and $f(x)-f(y) \leq 0$ .

I did the plot of the function and I got  $21$ by looking at the plot, but I'm not sure this is correct and I also want to know if there's a way to do this in a more precise manner. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up one of the inequalities. Current version is correct

Comment: Isn't the answer $8\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two curves are $(x+3)^2+(y+3)^2\leq4^2$ which is a circle.
And $x^2-y^2+6(x-y)\leq0$

To make the solution become even more simpler, I will the coordinate axis such that centre of circle lies at origin. That is by replacing $x$ by $X-3$ and similarly $y$ , The curves in new  coordinate system are.

$X^2+Y^2\leq4^2$

And

$(X-Y)(X+Y)\leq0$

Notice how the two pair of lines are perpendicular and passes through centre of circle!
**( Emphasize on this)**

That means that they are subtending an arc of $\pi/2$ at the centre of circle. And also since there are two such arc, the required area is essentially half the area of circle. 
Which is $\frac{1}{2}*\pi*(4)^2$